# Solve dependency problem with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Here I have a code which is translating one sting (s5) into another (s4). 
A table is used for that and to make sure, that nothing appears twice in a row. So each element, except the first one, is dependent on the one before. E.g. the part is 'cd', so the element before the new one is a 'c', then the code will look up the dictionary at c and will translate the 'd' into a '2'.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pathos

s5 = 'bcdabadbcadbcabdcbadcbadcbadcbadcbadcbadcbadcbadcbadcbadcbadcbadcbadcbd'

def S5_to_S4_new(s5, ):

    table = {
        'a': {'d': '0', 'c': '1', 'b': '2'},
        'b': {'a': '0', 'd': '1', 'c': '2'},
        'c': {'b': '0', 'a': '1', 'd': '2'},
        'd': {'c': '0', 'b': '1', 'a': '2'}
    }

    s4 = ''
    for i in range(len(s5) - 1, 0, -1):
        s4 = table[s5[i]][s5[i - 1]] + s4
    s4 = table[s5[0]]['a'] + s4

    print(s4)

    return s4

pathos.helpers.freeze_support()
pool = pathos.multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 2)
s4 = pool.map(S5_to_S4_new, s5)
```

I would to use multiprocessing in the for loop so that everything becomes more time efficient. The problem is, that, with the map function, you don't know where the string will be cut and that the translation of the elements is dependent on the elements before them. Therefore I always get this error:

```
multiprocess.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/Users/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/test/Test.py", line 19, in S5_to_S4_new
    s4 = table[s5[0]]['a'] + s4
KeyError: 'a'
```

How would you solve this problem so that multiprocessing can be used here to get the correct translation?

I thought about pre-splitting s5 and assigning it to specific processes.

Comment: check here- https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: I did, but couldn't find an instant solution .. did you?

Comment: `map` should treat your string as list of chars and split it on every char - and every process gets only one char. You should split it manually - if it possible. But if every char depends on previous char then it is useless beacuse one process would have to wait for result from previous process and it will run as long as in one process - or maybe even longer.

Comment: I agree! 

so, any other Ideas how I could make this loop faster with multiprocessing? what could I change/do

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've defined `table` but are referencing `dna_inv_table`

Comment: sry. actually its the same table .. I mistyped
so this you can ignore